# Python - module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'Table' error

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I am using Python with Conda environment and installed pyarrow with:
`conda install pyarrow`

After that tried following code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
# Convert from Pandas to Arrow
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
# Convert back to Pandas
df_new = table.to_pandas()
```

getting the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'Table'
```

I tried re-creating a new Conda environment (by following https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyarrow) and running:

```
conda create -n pypq python=3.6 anaconda
source activate pypq
conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
```

Got the same error:
`AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'Table'`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please also post links to the outputs of the `conda` commands so that we see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have `pyarrow` installed via `pip` and `conda` or installed it with one of them and removed with the other. In such situations, your best choice is to recreate the conda environment. Also when recreating this environment, take care to only use dependencies from the `defaults` channel or the `conda-forge` channel. Mixing these two can also lead to problems, e.g. when the packages `libboost` and `boost-cpp` are installed at the same time, things break.

Comment: So I should create a new Conda env and install it with `conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow` ?

Comment: Updated question - tried re-creating Conda environment and still have the same issue..

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, please don't mix Anaconda's defaults channel with `defaults`. Use `conda install pyarrow` as you have created an environment from `defaults` or create your environment with `conda create -n pypq python=3.6 pandas numpy -c conda-forge`.

Comment: Tried `conda deactivate;
conda remove -n pypq --all;
conda create -n pypq python=3.6 pandas numpy -c conda-forge;
conda activate pypq;
python pyarrow.py; `  Got same error: `AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'Table'`

Comment: Another source could be that you have `pyarrow` installed in your base conda installation. Try `conda deactivate; conda uninstall pyarrow`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pyarrow library is not successfully installed. Please try below two code

```
conda uninstall pyarrow
conda install pyarrow
```

Comment: Don't use `pip` in a conda environment, only use `conda` to manage dependencies there that are provided by conda.

Comment: Is it not your own environment? Then check above code

Comment: @HaseeAmarathunga - Updated question - tried re-creating Conda environment and still have the same issue..